# What does $F^n$ mean in the case of fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

I am reading notes for Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and came across this expression.

$$\exists F, \mathcal{V}_F(I):\{\xi \in F^n:f(\xi)=0, \forall f\in I\}\neq \emptyset$$

Here, $F=\mathcal{P}/m$ is a quotient field in the polynomial ring, $\mathcal{P}$, and $I$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{P}$.

I'm not quite sure what $F^n$ means--I think it may mean the elements that has an nth root in $F$ but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Just the $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$?

Comment: It simply means the set of $n$-tuples of elements from the field.

Comment: $F^n$ here is defined to be the cartesian product $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n F$.  If $\zeta = (\zeta_1, ... , \zeta_n)$ is an element of $F^n$, and $f(X_1, ... , X_n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ variables, then one often writes $$f(\zeta)$$ to mean the evaluation $f(\zeta_1, ... , \zeta_n)$.

Comment: oh. I forgot about that possibility...

Comment: D_S is right. $F^n$ is the affine space in $n$ variables over $F$.